# How to assign a value in a data frame based on multiple conditions of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, one consisting of numerical values called 'esame':

```
         media    id_poll fin
1   5.330000e+00     360   1
2   6.833333e-02     361   0
3   0.000000e+00     362   0
4             NA     363   0
5   8.200000e-01     364   0
6   3.416667e-01     365   0
7   0.000000e+00     366   0
8   0.000000e+00     367   0
9   0.000000e+00     368   0
10            NA     369   0
11  6.150000e-01     370   0
12  0.000000e+00     371   0
13  0.000000e+00     372   0
14            NA     373   0
15  0.000000e+00     374   0
16  0.000000e+00     375   0
17  0.000000e+00     376   0
18  1.298333e+00     377   0
```

And the second one consisting of numerical ranges which I would like to use to check in which range the 'media' field of the first data.frame is.
If it's in the first range I would like to assign "1" to the field "fin" of the first data.frame, if it's in the second I would like to assign "2" and so on.

So here it is the second data.frame with some of the conditions I'll need:

```
Range1  Range2  Range3  Range4  ID
0.5     9.9     29.9    >30    360
0.5     15.9    49.9    >50    361
0       4.9     24.9    >25    362
```

First of all I suppose I won't need to declare Range4 as it's already an information included in Range3. I removed the initial value of all numerical ranges as I need just a single number to check against (or so I think). The same row for ID 360 could be written as:

```
Range1  Range2  Range3    Range4    ID
 0.5    0.6-9.9  10-29.9    >30    360
```

So my guess is to do something like this:

```
esame$fin<-ifelse (esame$media<0.6 & datofinale$id_poll=="360", "1", "0")
```

I could substitute the "0" value with another 'ifelse' statement and go on manually.
Is there any faster way to do that? (the list containing all the condititions is actually pretty larger than the example).

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Not too nice, but this should work:

```
require(dplyr)

inner_join(Data,Data1,by=c("id_poll"="ID")) %>% rowwise() %>% 
        mutate(fin = findInterval(media,c(-Inf,Range1,Range2,Range3),left.open=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Reproducible data

```
esame <- structure(list(media = c(5.33, 0.06833333, 0, NA, 0.82, 0.3416667, 
0, 0, 0, NA, 0.615, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1.298333), id_poll = 360:377, 
fin = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("media", "id_poll", "fin"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000014320788>)

df1 <- structure(list(Range1 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0), Range2 = c(9.9, 15.9, 
4.9), Range3 = c(29.9, 49.9, 24.9), Range4 = c(">30", ">50", 
">25"), ID = 360:362), .Names = c("Range1", "Range2", "Range3", 
"Range4", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000014320788>)
```

#### dplyr solution

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- left_join(esame1, df1, by=c("id_poll" = "ID")) %>%
         mutate(fin = case_when( media > Range3 ~ 4,
                                 media > Range2 ~ 3,
                                 media > Range1 ~ 2,
                                 media <= Range1 ~ 1,
                                 is.na(Range1) == T ~ 0))  # else case
```

#### Output

```
        media  ID fin Range1 Range2 Range3 Range4
1  5.33000000 360   2    0.5    9.9   29.9    >30
2  0.06833333 361   1    0.5   15.9   49.9    >50
3  0.00000000 362   1    0.0    4.9   24.9    >25
4          NA 363   0     NA     NA     NA   <NA>
5  0.82000000 364   0     NA     NA     NA   <NA>
```

Comment: You could skip the `rename()` and simply do `left_join(esame, df1, by = c("id_poll" = "ID"))`

Comment: Real nice and understandable solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @StevenBeaupré

Comment: Can you think about a solution using the plyr package instead of dplyr? I'm using plyr in my code and I think there will be some problems loading both, particulary when using the summarize function.

Comment: @PaoloVeronesi As long as you load `plyr` before you load `dplyr`, you should be okay. You should also consider loading `tidyverse`, which contains both `plyr` and `dplyr` and might help you to avoid this issue

Comment: @ChiPak Please validate your statements. `plyr` is **not** part of the `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 0):

We can consider each row in the range data.frame as a vector and ask whether the current media value is greater than the value in this vector.

For simplicity, I'm assuming that all values in the first data.frame has a correspondent in the second, and that they are all ordered the same way.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(esame))  {
  greater.than <- esame[i,1]>range[i,1:3] #this returns a vector of TRUE (greater than this range) and FALSE (within) you want the first FALSE
  esame$fin <- max(which(greater.than))+1 #returns the position of the last TRUE +1, which is the position of the first FALSE
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but I'm not very fond of cycles in R... Anyway thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

`dat` - first df, `tad` - second. It will put `0` if `NA`, nested `ifelse()` and assume that first range is from 0 to present value. However show some example result to check if it works properly.

```
dat$fin <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) ifelse(dat[x,1] >= tad[x,1] & !is.na(dat[x,1]), 1, ifelse(dat[x,1] >= tad[x,2] & !is.na(dat[x,1]), 2, ifelse(dat[x,1] >= tad[x,3] & !is.na(dat[x,1]), 3, 0))))

>dat
       media id_poll fin
1 5.33000000     360   1
2 0.06833333     361   0
3 0.00000000     362   1
```